# Python Military Time formula and string formatting

Tags: python, time, formatting

I have created a function to take a string input "minutes-since-midnight" and convert it into military time.For example- 365 = 0605,441 = 0721,864 = 1424. For some reason my outputs are: 066, 077, 1414. Can someone please explain to me what I am doing wrong

```
def military_time(minutes):
    if minutes < 600:
        hour = minutes // 60 
        minute = minutes % 60
        print("0{0:0}{0:0}".format(hour,minute))
    elif 600 < minutes < 720:
        hour = minutes // 60
        minute = minutes % 60
        print("{0:0}{0:0}".format(hour,minute))
    elif minutes == 720:
        hour = 1200
        print(hour)
    else:
        hour = ((minutes-720) // 60) + 12
        minute = (minutes) % 60
        print("{0:0}{0:0}".format(hour,minute))
```

Comment: def military_time(minutes):
        if minutes < 600:
            hour = minutes // 60 
            minute = minutes % 60
            print("0{0:0}{0:0}".format(hour,minute))
        elif 600 < minutes < 720:
            hour = minutes // 60
           minute = minutes % 60
        print("{0:0}{0:0}".format(hour,minute))
    elif minutes == 720:
        hour = 1200
        print(hour)
    else:
        hour = ((minutes-720) // 60) + 12
        minute = (minutes) % 60
        print("{0:0}{0:0}".format(hour,minute))

military_time(365)
military_time(441)
military_time(864)

Comment: For some reason, stack overflow is not formatting my code snippets properly. I apologize for the inconvenience. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Stack Overflow wont let me edit my question, unless I dont know where the edit button is.

Comment: Thank you @depperm

Comment: @hiroprotagonist answer is right, and his comment is especially important, if you changed `{0:0}{0:0}` to `{0:0}{1:0}` it would display the right numbers but not the right formatting, you were on the right track

Answer (score 1):

you can use [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec) to pad your integers with zeros if necessary:

```
def military_time(minutes):
    minutes %= 1440  # does not make sense if more than 24h
    h, m = divmod(minutes, 60)
    print("{0:02d}{1:02d}".format(h, m))

military_time(365)  # 0605
military_time(441)  # 0721
military_time(864)  # 1424
```

also note that your format string referenced the first argument twice (you had `{0}{0}` instead of `{0}{1}`).

Comment: shouldn't 365 be 605?

Comment: now that you mention it: yes... will investigate. ok. fixed.

Comment: how do i automatically add a 0 in front of 1-digit numbers and 00 if  divmod(minutes, 60) = 0

Comment: as i have shown in my code: `{0:02d}` means: the first argument (that is the first `0`) , then the formatting behind the `:` which means `d` for an integer to be formatted; `2` places reserved for it `0` zero padded. the link in my answer leads to the documentation of all that.